# Adding an image to array elements

Tags: c#, arrays, image

I am making a card game where I have created 10 different cards, I have implemented the pictures into the program in the resources area on the right. My card structure looks like this:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        cards = new PlayCard[10];
        cards[0] = new PlayCard("Harry", 97, 33, 40);
        cards[1] = new PlayCard("Dave", 80, 91, 41);
        cards[2] = new PlayCard("Randle", 90, 13, 45);
        cards[3] = new PlayCard("Zach", 30, 98, 81);
        cards[4] = new PlayCard("Shorty", 30, 89, 99);
        cards[5] = new PlayCard("Matt", 75, 81, 72);
        cards[6] = new PlayCard("Aaron", 89, 82, 80);
        cards[7] = new PlayCard("Ryan", 25, 83, 71);
        cards[8] = new PlayCard("Stephen", 96, 100, 100);
        cards[9] = new PlayCard("David", 90, 37, 70);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I'm wondering how I get the corresponding picture to show up determined on which card is shown

Thanks

Comment: I think you're going to have to give more detail of which UI you're using (WinForms, WPF, Win8, HTML).  This will affect the way you store image references.

Comment: Indeed. You're going to have to load the textures somehow, and then give the individual cards references to those textures.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`ImageList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You can then name each image to correspond with your names. There is a good introduction to ImageLists and how to add images at run-time and design-time [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/imagelist).

First add images (shown at run-time):

```
imageList1.Images.Add("pic1", Image.FromFile("c:\\mypic.jpg"));
```

To remove image from collection:

```
imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
imageList1.Images..RemoveByKey("pic1");
```

To access images, get image from the image collection:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images["David"];
```

or for your array:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[cards[i][0]];
```

I hope this helps.

---

*Edit. to address the comments of the above not being OOP. Instead of using an `ImageList` you could add an `Image` to your `PlayCard` object. There is also an option to use a `Dictionary<string, Image>` to handle this mapping, but again this could be construed as non-OOP.*

Comment: It'll work, but it's really not OOP, and it burdens resource managing for no reason - you'll have to mirror the add/remove process in both collections. 

Also, if he wants to rename a card, you'll have to go and change the name of the card..

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as a property to your PlayCard class, then assign an image to each playcard (easiest way - change your constructor). Each playcard will know its image, so it's really easy to implement it in your existing code without many modifications.